# Visually Build Insert, Update, and Delete Functions for DataGridView Control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, datagrid

### QUESTION:

What is the proper way to  **insert**, **update**, and **delete** statements visually inside of Visual Studio for a Data Grid View control such as we do with the select statement?

### BACKGROUND:

I've found many tutorials online showing how you can programmatically insert, update and delete records via the data found in the data grid when it's in edit mode however none that show the built in, "visual" functions such as we have with the select query.

Now when connecting to the database, Visual Studio generates a DataSet in which we can actually go in under SqlTableAdapter and find our select query that was generated for us but when we add an insert query (which is possible!) into that interface it shows up along side our select query such as here:

[image: SqlTableAdapterQuery]

However when going back to the data grid view and selecting "Add Query"  the new insert query doesn't show up:

[image: Add new query to data grid view]
[image: Choose existing query data grid view]

Comment: If you take a close look at the 'Search Criteria Builder' window, you can see 'Select a patametrized query to load data'. *Load Data* needs a Select statement, so it's not supposed to show an Insert statement. What'ts your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

To **visually add Insert, Update, and Delete statements to a data grid** follow the steps above and in "TableAdapter Configuration Wizzard" select advanced options as shown below.

---

[image: Advanced Options - Table Adapter Configuration Wizzard]